# Some questions on the identity $\sum_{n=k+2}^{\infty} \binom{n-1}{k} (\zeta(n) -1) = 1 $

Tags: reference-request, binomial-coefficients, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

On p. 263 of Borwein's [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700003368) entitled “Computational Strategies for the Riemann zeta function”, the following identity is stated: $$\sum_{n=k+2}^{\infty} \binom{n-1}{k} (\zeta(n) -1) =1 .$$It is valid for all nonnegative integer $k$.

The author points to other formulas that are relevant, including (43) on p. 262. However, I don't see how this identity follows from any previously established series evaluations, nor have I found a reference in the article with regards to this particular identity.

**Questions**

1. How can the aforementioned identity be derived? Can you provide a proof?
2. Are there any references to articles or books that describe and prove this identity?
3. Can the identity be generalised? Are there variations of it involving binomial sums which are also valid for all nonnegative $k$?

Comment: The obvious thing to try is to write $\zeta(n)-1=\sum_{m=2}^\infty m^{-n}$, put that into the formula and reverse the summation. How does that work?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{n=k+2}^{\infty} \binom{n-1}{k} (\zeta(n) -1) = \sum_{n=k+2}\binom{n-1}{k}\sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^{n}} \\
= \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=k+2}^{\infty} \binom{n-1}{k}\frac{1}{m^{n}}
$$
From
$$\binom{n-1}{k} = (-1)^{n-1-k}\binom{-1-k}{n-1-k}$$
we have
$$
(sum) = \sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k+2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1-k}\binom{-1-k}{n-1-k}\frac{1}{m^{n}} \\
=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^{k+1}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{-k-1}{n}\left(-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{n} \\
=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^{k+1}}\left[\left(1 - \frac{1}{m}\right)^{-k-1} - 1\right]\qquad(\text{by Newton's binomial theorem}) \\
=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(m-1)^{k+1}} - \frac{1}{m^{k+1}}\right) = 1.
$$

Comment: Thank you! Do you also have any ideas about question 2 and 3?

Comment: @MaxMuller Sorry, I have no idea for 2. For 3, since the results essentially obtained by changing the order of summation and telescoping, we may get similar results by going backwards (start with a similar telescoping sum and obtain some nontrivial results).

Answer (score 1):

1. Using [the integral representation of the Riemann Zeta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) we have that $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dbinom{n+k-1}{k}\left(\zeta\left(n+k\right)-1\right)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{u^{n+k-1}}{k!\left(n-1\right)!}\left(\frac{1}{e^{u}-1}-\frac{1}{e^{u}}\right)du$$ $$=\frac{1}{k!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}u^{k}e^{-u}du=1.$$
2. I don't know references to this identity.
3. Note that, in this formulation, the results may be generalized for all $k\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$, obviously taking $k!=\Gamma\left(k+1\right)$. About the “variations” I'm not sure I understand what you are asking: do you mean sums with Zeta function and binomials? Or parametric sums with Zeta and binomials such that the result is constant? However, in the link I posted there are a lot of sum involving Zeta function.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes, it's a bit hard to describe what kind of variations I mean. I'm looking for results that describe sums with infinitely many lower bounds, have binomial terms, and preferably also amount to the same sum. It would be a generalization of the identity I named if it introduces yet another variable and all sums would still amount to 1 (or another constant).

Comment: perhaps the MO version of the question makes it slightly clearer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372099/do-generalizations-of-the-identity-sum-n-k2-infty-binomn-1k-zeta . Please let me know by the way what you think about the exchange in the comments between Alapan Das and me.

Comment: @MaxMuller I'll read what you wrote on MO as soon as I have time. However, a simple "variation" starting from what I wrote can be this: since we have shown that the identity holds for any real non-negative $k$, if we take the derivative from both sides with respect to $k$ we obtain a series with binomials and Zeta function (but also Digamma function and the derivative of Zeta) which is $0$ for every real non-negative $k$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{n\ =\ k + 2}^{\infty}
{n - 1 \choose k}\bracks{\zeta\pars{n} - 1} = 1}:\
{\Large ?}}$
Note that
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n = k + 2}^{\infty}{n - 1 \choose k} =
\bracks{z^{k}}\sum_{n = k + 2}^{\infty}
\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} =
\bracks{z^{k}}{\pars{1 + z}^{k + 1} \over
1-\pars{1 + z}}
\\[5mm] = &\ -\bracks{z^{k + 1}}\pars{1 + z}^{k + 1}
= \bbx{\large -1} \\ &
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&\mbox{such that}
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{n\ =\ k + 2}^{\infty}
{n - 1 \choose k}\bracks{\zeta\pars{n} - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
1\ +\
\underbrace{\sum_{n\ =\ k + 2}^{\infty}
{n - 1 \choose k}\zeta\pars{n}}
_{\ds{=\ \color{red}{\large 0}}}\ =\
\bbx{\Large 1} \\ &
\end{align}
$\ds{\bbx{\mbox{It remains to prove that}\
\sum_{n\ =\ k + 2}^{\infty}
{n - 1 \choose k}\zeta\pars{n} =
\color{red}{\large 0}}}$.

---

With [A & S $\ds{\bf\color{black}{6.3.14}}$ identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm)
$\ds{\pars{~\left.\vphantom{\large A}\Psi\pars{z}
\right\vert_{\ \verts{z}\ <\ 1} = -\gamma +
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\zeta\pars{n}z^{n - 1}~}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = k + 2}^{\infty}
{n - 1 \choose k}\zeta\pars{n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{n = k + 2}^{\infty}
{n - 1 \choose k}
\bracks{z^{n - 1}}\braces{\pars{-1}^{n}
\bracks{\Psi\pars{z} + \gamma}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\bracks{z^{0}}\bracks{\Psi\pars{z} + \gamma}
\sum_{n = k + 2}^{\infty}
\pars{-\,{1 \over z}}^{n - 1}{n - 1 \choose k}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\bracks{z^{0}}\bracks{\Psi\pars{z} + \gamma}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\pars{-\,{1 \over z}}^{n + k}{n + k \choose k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{k + 1}
\bracks{z^{k}}\bracks{\Psi\pars{z} + \gamma}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\pars{-\,{1 \over z}}^{n}{n + k \choose n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{k + 1}
\bracks{z^{k}}\bracks{\Psi\pars{z} + \gamma}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\pars{-\,{1 \over z}}^{n}
{- k - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{k + 1}
\bracks{z^{k}}\bracks{\Psi\pars{z} + \gamma}
\bracks{\pars{1 + {1 \over z}}^{-k - 1} - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{k + 1}
\bracks{z^{k}}\bracks{\Psi\pars{z} + \gamma}
\bracks{{z^{k + 1} \over \pars{1 + z}^{k + 1}} - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\large 0} \\ &
\end{align}